# Will an HVAC vent interfere with an Infrared Sensor?

Tags: infrared-radiation

A 360 degree ceiling mount [infrared sensor](https://img.acuitybrands.com/public-assets/catalog/757191/cmr-family.pdf?abl_version=09%2F19%2F2023%2019%3A37%3A54&DOC_Type=SPEC_SHEET) is to be installed in the center of a small room.  An HVAC (heating, ventilation  & Air Conditioning) register is located in the ceiling, near the center of the room.

Will airflow (warm / cool),  from the register, interfere or block infrared energy from a source (person)?  Assume the HVAC airflow is between the person and the sensor.  I realize that a physical barrier (including glass / plastic) will block infrared.